# Why does this SQL query work when I have an invalid subquery? - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

I made a mistake in writing a query and I am trying to understand why this query even runs.  Here is the query:

```
select * from user
where user_id in (select user_id from admin);
```

In this query, there is no field `user_id` in the `admin` table, but the query still runs and in the end returns unexpected results. There is a `user_id` in the `user` table.

When I change the field to something that doesn't exist in the primary table, then the query doesn't run.

```
select * from user
where user_id in (select test_id from admin);
```

I also tried to run it with a non existent table, which also didn't run.

```
select * from user
where user_id in (select user_id from blah);
```

Can someone please explain why the first query works?  Is there a better way to write these queries where mistakes will be easier to find?

Comment: "*Is there a better way to write these queries*" - yes, always prefix column names with a table alias

Answer (score 1):

*Always* qualify your column references.  You think the first query is:

```
select u.*
from user u
where u.user_id in (select a.user_id from admin a);
```

Because `a.user_id` does not exist, it is interpreted as:

```
select u.*
from user u
where u.user_id in (select u.user_id from admin a);
```

This is testing two things that you probably don't care about:

- `u.user_id` is not null
- `admin` has at least one row

Comment: Obviously adding alias will help, but it is still odd that the query would run.  This also makes for a difficult defect to find.  Why is it finding `u.user_id` in `admin`?

Comment: @jhamm . . . Those are the scoping rules of SQL.  If a column referenced in a subquery is not recognized, then SQL looks to the outer query for the reference.  It cannot do this if the column is correctly qualified (i.e. includes the table reference).